# Atom editor highlighting issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, atom-editor

Why would an element be highlighted  following a transition property in css? I'm using Atom text editor.

the background property is highlighted in my editor.

```
.squares {
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  border-radius: 15%;
  transition: background 0.3;
}
```

[ A screenshot of the highlighting ][1]

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Ih1.png

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just found that out through some searching.

Comment: Actually, it would be useful to see the highlighting, so how about posting code *and* screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the syntax highlighter for CSS. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property), "background" is a valid transition-property. However, the syntax-highlighter package adds the classes `syntax--invalid` and `syntax--deprecated`.

It turns out that any of [these properties](https://github.com/atom/language-css/blob/v0.43.0/grammars/css.cson#L626-L629) are marked the same. Since those rules are meant for something else, it's clearly a bug that you should probably [report](https://github.com/atom/language-css/issues).

Comment: I have added a photo to the original post